# What is the regular expression to replace "[" and "]" from a string array?

Tags: java

I am trying to replace `[` and `]` characters from a string array `[ab, cd ,ef]` to get the output like this:

```
ab, cd, ef
```

using the regular expression

```
(^\s*|[\n\t\r\[\]])
```

but I am not able to get the desired output.

Comment: How does your code look like? Your regex is overcomplicated but it should be able to find `[` and `]` (and few other characters) so only problem is how you are using it.

Comment: Try escaping '[' with '\'. => "\["

Comment: @RavindraHV OP does escape `[` and `]` but didn't format his question properly to show it. Try refreshing this page to see updated version of question.

Comment: Right. Thanks. Kimia sn's answer is what I was about to suggest. Also creating a new array without the first and last characters will do just as well. But I guess Michael Markidis's answer is what OP's looking for.

Comment: why dont you follow the @kimia sn answer???

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why don't use replace method from String class?

```
String str = "[ab, cd ,ef]";

str.replace("[", "").replace("]", "");
```

Answer (score 1):

This will work:

```
String str = "[ab, cd, ef]";

System.out.println(str.replaceAll("[\\[\\]]", ""));
```

**Explanation**: It uses the [character class](http://www.regular-expressions.info/charclass.html) in regex to replace all the characters you don't want.

**Outputs**:

```
ab, cd ,ef
```

Comment: Sorry, I deleted my comment by mistake. Here's again: For as far as I understand, `[ab, cd ,ef]` is what is displayed when the OP print's out an array of strings. It's not the string itself.

Comment: What you are doing is creating a `String` and then setting `"[ab, cd, ef]"` as it's value.
Your solution works, but you could modify the answer by replacing the `String` by a string array, just for clarity.

Comment: @JavaNoob I'm not quite sure what you are getting at. A string array, nor any array for that matter, has the actual "[" and "]" characters. How could I possibly provide my example without using a string?

Comment: You could do it defining a string array like this `String[] str = { "20", "30", "40" };`

Comment: @JavaNoob OK. and from there how would you remove the "[" and "]" characters?

Comment: With this: `Arrays.toString(str).replaceAll("[\\[\\]]", "")`.

Comment: Yeah, but the OP was not asking how to convert a string array to a string. They were really asking how to remove the brackets, which is exactly what these answers as well as the answers in the duplicate provide. BTW: The duplicate has no mention of an array. Overall, I think starting the example from an Array is a moot point.

Comment: No, he wasn't, but if you want to print out a string array, you have to convert it to a string with `Array.toString();` otherwise you'll have the memory location of the array.
The duplicate doesn't mention an array, but this post does. The solution to the OP's problem can still be found in the duplicate, but it's not exactly the same thing. I don't think it matters anymore though, since the question has already been marked as a duplicate.

Answer (score 0):

Although its not a regular expression, if I have understood what you want correctly (you are doing a to-string on the array and trimming the result so as to get the CSV) - this will work too :

```
String data = "[Hello World]";
System.out.println(String.copyValueOf(data.toCharArray(),1,data.length()-2));
```

That said, you ideally should not be doing it this way since its not flexible (if you want a semi-colon or a colon instead of a comma then you have to do a replace all over again !). Ideally you should be using for-each to iterate and then appending the appropriate separator.